# Get "this field is required" in django-auth-registration

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

## What I want to do

Make a user to register to `django Authentication`

## Version

`django` : 3.1

`djangorestframework`:3.11.1

`python` : 3.7.6

`django-allauth` : 0.42.0

`django-rest-auth` : 0.9.5

## Situation

I entered a registration page that `django` provides by accessing to `localhost:8000/rest-auth/registration/`.
In order to register to the site, I entered `username`, `password1` and `password2` in fields. However, every time I sent POST request, I got an error and that says it below.

```
{
    "password1": [
        "This field is required"
    ],
    "password2": [
        "This field is required"
    ]
}
```

I absolutely typed exact same passwords in these fields. And, I do really not know why I get this error although I surely entered passwords.

How could I fix it out? I would like you to teach me how to do that.

Thank you very much.[image]

### models.py

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('メールアドレスは必須項目です。')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

# Django提供のカスタムユーザーのFieldを決定
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    profile = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    background = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        ('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=(
            '管理サイトへのアクセス権を持っているかどうか'),
    )

    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        ('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            'ユーザーがアクティブかどうか'
        ),
    )
    # createdAt, updatedAt は時系列順等に並べたいモデルに付与
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ["usename", "email"]

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

### views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

### setting.py

```
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import pymysql
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 0, "final", 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*********'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "rest_framework",
    "app",
    "corsheaders",
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'extra_exchange.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'extra_exchange.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'extra_exchange',
        'USER': '*******',
        'PASSWORD': '********',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja-JP'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Rest Frame Work
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser',
        'djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser',
    ),
}

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000"
]

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
```

I recreated my django project and create a new `User` model by extending `User` which `Django` originally provides with us like above. However I still have the same issue.

Comment: can you post your forms, models and views

Comment: @EkremÜçüncü I just edited my post and added my models, settings, and views. If it alright with you, I would like you to check them.

Comment: why have you not declared the passwords in your User model

Comment: also you madd a typo in the required field, it should username you forget the r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. I edited `RegisterSerializer` then it worked.

Comment: what did you changed ?

Comment: @Toshi023Yuki please explain in more detail what you did

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, this occurred because I employed `djangorestframework_camel_case`.

The `password1` is transformed into `password_1` in snake_case. To address this, I modified all instances of the string "password1" to "password_1."

Below is the code for my solution.

```py
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class UserRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=128)
    birthday = serializers.DateField()

    @cached_property
    def fields(self):
        from rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers import BindingDict
        fields = BindingDict(self)
        for key, value in self.get_fields().items():
            if key == "password1":
                key = "password_1"
            if key == "password2":
                key = "password_2"
            fields[key] = value
        return fields

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password_1'] != data['password_2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return data

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password_1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'name': self.validated_data.get('name', ''),
            'birthday': self.validated_data.get('birthday', None),
        }

    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        user.name = data.get('name', '')
        user.birthday = data.get('birthday', '')
        user.save()
```

---

PS:

I found out a better solution.
You can configure djangorestframework_camel_case to exclude certain keys from parsing.
[here](https://github.com/vbabiy/djangorestframework-camel-case#ignore-keys)

I merely add this configure in settings.py

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    "JSON_UNDERSCOREIZE": {
        "ignore_keys": ("password1", "password2"),
    },
```

---

OR:

If you want to ignore underscore before number every time, it should be better.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    'JSON_UNDERSCOREIZE': {
        'no_underscore_before_number': True,
    },
```